Error on publishing media on graph.instagram.com - error_subcode 2207008
I want to publish a story on my instagram account.
So I use the new Instagram API with Instagram login (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login/migration-guide)
I can get a token and create a media container, but when I want to publish the media the API returns an error.
I did the following:
First I created a media container
https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/{IG_USER_ID}/media?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

{
    "image_url": "https://example.com/example.jpg"
}

A media containerId is returns, so this is working as expected.
Than I use the media containerId to publish the media:
https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/{IG_USER_ID}/media_publish?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

{
    "creation_id": 12345
}

I expect a success, but I get the following response:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 24,
        "error_subcode": 2207008,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Media Builder not found",
        "error_user_msg": "De Media Builder with creation-ID 12345 does not exist or is expired.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AY5DQvsrevDfesaMiZNL-7"
    }
}

I know a facebook page was required in the past, but with the new Login with Instagram feature this should work.
Has someone the same problem and solved this already?

I have exactly the same issue.

same here idk what's going on

I have the exact problem, and I haven't found any solution

Here is the same issue registered as bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1165928011337391/
